# EventBus - The Subscribe method is never used

Tags: android

In fragment , I want to receive message ,but the Subscribe method is never used,
the method does not receive messages that I post

fragment code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.BackgroundThread)
public void getMessage(Integer integer){
        hotDao = new HotDao(this);
        hotDao.getDataHot(null);
}
```

In the MainActivity ,I post

code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guide);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(1);
    loadView= (LoadView) findViewById(R.id.activity_guide_loadview);
    startMainActivity();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because the message is sent before the bus has enough time to get initialized.

To check that, just try to delay the post for 1 or 2 seconds (in your MainAcytivity) by doing something like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guide);

    loadView= (LoadView) findViewById(R.id.activity_guide_loadview);
    startMainActivity();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
      public void run() {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(1);
      }
    }, 1500);
}
```

Also you can use a [Sticky Event](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/) so that your fragment can get it even if the event is sent before its creation.

**Edit**: As stated Björn Kechel the correct solution is to put the post in the onResume of the MainActivity. The delay was just used to check if the problem where coming from the fact the bus was initialized after the message was sent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer，it solved my problem。However I see a lot of demo not delay ths post .I hope you can tell me when I need to delay

Comment: Yes, you are right, the delay was just used to confirm you that the event was sent before the bus get registered in the fragment. Please try to send the post in the onResume of the MainActivity

Comment: You should not rely on a delay because it will not work if the fragment creation needs more time for some reason. Using a sticky event without a delay or posting the event in onResume() are the proper solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the event too early, take a look at the fragment lifecycle:

[image]

So if you call it in onResume, you should be good to go. An alternative is to use [Sticky Events](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/)

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.BackgroundThread)
```